# What does 'picket fence' mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning, lyrics, music

Today I was listening to a song from Fall Out boy called *Miss missing you*.
At one point in the song, they sing the line: "Baby you were my picket fence".

I know what a picket fence is, but I don't know if it makes any sense here. Maybe it has another meaning?

Here's the full passage:

> I will sing to you everyday, if it will take away the pain
> Oh, and I heard you've got it, got it so bad
> 'Cause I am the best you'll ever have
> Baby you were my picket fence
> I miss missing you, now and then

So what does that line mean?

Comment: One for our American friends. It makes no sense in BrE. And yes, I too know what a picket fence is. I did find one definition which may have a bearing *"a picket fence as a symbol of middle-class domesticity and contentment"* so maybe the singer is trying to apply that to the lady.

Comment: It has the usual meaning but is being used figuratively (metaphorically) here. If you're interested in what the symbolism represents, I think that [Writing SE](https://writing.stackexchange.com/) might be a good place to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[As Wiktionary explains,](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/white_picket_fence) the phrase "white picket fence" is often used as "a symbol of the ideal middle-class suburban life, with a large house, family, and peaceful lifestyle."

The song presumably means that the singer used to see the addressee as the foundation of a comfortable, conventional, and/or peaceful life.